# sql insert into lookup tables' association tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm updating 3 lookup tables' association tables like so:

```
insert into LookUpTable1_AssociationTable1 ([LookupId],[AssociationId])
select Id as LookupId, 4 as AssociationId from LookupTable1

insert into LookUpTable2_AssociationTable2 ([LookupId],[AssociationId])
select Id as LookupId, 4 as AssociationId from LookupTable2
```

I have 4 records in my Association master table. So I can run the above replacing the hard-coded '4' with each id in my association master table, but can i do it as a set somehow? Just run a "set based" (not procedural) sql that takes all 4 records in association table and performs the statements above automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if i understand your intent correctly. Check whether below query suits your needs.

```
insert into LookUpTable1_AssociationTable1 ([LookupId],[AssociationId])
select 
    l.Id as LookupId
    ,a.Id as AssociationId 
from
    LookupTable1 l
    cross join Association a
```